# In C# is it possible to have an custom Indexer property of a type that is NOT a string or an int?

Tags: c#, properties, unity-game-engine, indices, indexer

In C# is it possible to have an Indexer property of a type that is not a string or an int?

For example I have a custom object that is a map of 2D vector coordinates. Taking the basics of my map class to be...

```
public class TileMap
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The holds an array of tiles
    /// </summary>
    MapTile[,] _map;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="PathFindingMapTile"/> with the specified position.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The <see cref="PathFindingMapTile"/>.
    /// </value>
    /// <param name="position">The position.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public MapTile this[Vector2 position]   // Indexer declaration
    {
        get
        { 
            int x = (int)position.x;
            int y = (int)position.y;
            return _map[x, y]; 
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TileMap"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="length">The length.</param>
    /// <param name="height">The height.</param>
    public TileMap(int length, int height)
    {
        _map = new MapTile[length, height];
    }

}
```

This compiles without issue. However the calling code fails with two errors

Base class

```
internal abstract class MyBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets (or privately sets) the tile map
    /// </summary>
    protected PathFindingMapTile[,] TileMap { get; private set; }
}
```

derived class

```
internal class MyDerived : MyBase
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        Vector2 possiblePosition;
        MapTile possibleTile = null;

        possibleTile = this.TileMap[possiblePosition]; // <-- This line wont compile
    }
}
```

Compile Errors:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Vector2' to 'int' 
Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2
```

Why two indices? I have stated just one, the position. Any suggestions?

**Update** - Following Rufus comment. Corrected return type of "Tilemap" property of the base class.

```
internal abstract class MyBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets (or privately sets) the tile map
    /// </summary>
    protected TileMap TileMap { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: You are treating the indexers as it would be a static property, but that is not the case. You needt instance of TileMap in order to use indexer?

Comment: Please show more of the calling code - in particular, do you have a *variable* called `TileMap`? (Just for clarity, try naming it something other than the name of your type...)

Comment: Well... I have got the calling code to compile using the following.

    possibleTile = TileMap[(int)possiblePosition.x, (int)possiblePosition.y];

...but that is clutching at straws!

Comment: Well it sounds like `TileMap` isn't of the type `TileMap` - but you need to show us more code...

Comment: Sorry I have not been clear. TileMap refers to a property of the same name as the type. I'll update the code!

Comment: Your `TileMap` property is not of type `TileMap`, it's of type `PathFindingMapTile[,] `, which requires two indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `TileMap` property is not of type `TileMap`, it's of type `PathFindingMapTile[,]`, which requires two indexes.

Comment: Sorry, I have now cleared up the example to show that "TileMap" is not referring to the static instance but is an instance property which has the same name as the type.

Comment: My bad. TileMap was originally an array of PathFindingMapTile, but I refactored that to be a TileMap object which had the array as an internal member. I had forgotten to refactor the property return type.

Thanks again.

Comment: Much too late in the evening and way too tired to spot it for myself!